# Problems encountered when Android uses camera to take pictures

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, android-file

When I used the camera in Android to take pictures, I always saved the first image in a row. Although I called file.delete to delete the original picture before taking pictures, there was no effect. How should this situation be handled?

The effect I want to achieve is just like what is written in the title, the user will directly take a new photo if they feel dissatisfied. I don't want to keep every picture he takes. So he wanted to use the same file name to save a photo that he was more satisfied with.

Comment: An app can use the same file name a hundred times.